# thread and deconstruction of functors

Tags: c++, multithreading, move

I'm trying to understand when the deconstructor of a functor (i.e. a class with `()` operator) is called when that functor is passed to a `thread`. But in the following example, the constructor is called for once but the deconstructor is called for three times?

According to

- What are the missing (two) calls to the constructor? Is it copy or move?
- If the move constructor is called, how can write the deconstructor so that it won't destroy the resources being moved? Imagine I open a file `run()` and close it in the `~run()`, calling it three times causes a problem of course.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class run {
public:
    run() { cout << "in run()" << endl; }
    ~run() { cout << "in ~run()" << endl; }
    void operator()() {};
};

int main() {
    run thread_r;
    thread t(thread_r);
    t.join();
}
```

Gives output:

```
in run()
in ~run()
in ~run()
in ~run()
```

Comment: Try `thread t(std::ref(thread_r));`. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3m7i49Zzs3fdikVX).

Comment: @KerrekSB dangerous advice without listing the caveats. I'd favour `thread t(std::move(thread_r));` or just `std::thread t(run{});`

Comment: @sehe So moving is preferred? If the functor contains a resource (e.g. a opened file), moving it and calling the `~run()` is problematic, right? Is there a way to sort of move the resource without calling the deconstructor?

Comment: My point was really, don't share resources across threads unless absolutely required. If you pass `std::ref(thread_r)` it will cause problems when others access `thread_r` or when it goes out of scope before the thread exits.

Answer (score 5):

Rule of 5, 3 and zero.

If you define a destructor, the compiler will still generate a default copy constructor and assignment operator.

Unfortunately, if you've defined a destructor it implies that you have some special handling around resource deallocation, so the default copy and assignment code will be plain wrong.

*It is good practice*, by which I mean "always do it, no excuses", to provide at least copy constructor and assignment operator, even if you delete them.

If you're going to supply these, you may as well go ahead and write correct move operators too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class run {
public:
    run() { cout << "in run()" << endl; }
    run(const run&) { cout << "copied()" << endl; }
    run(run&&) { cout << "moved()" << endl; }
    run& operator=(const run&) { cout << "copy-assigned()" << endl; return *this; }
    run& operator=(run &&) { cout << "move-assigned()" << endl; return *this; }
    ~run() { cout << "in ~run()" << endl; }
    void operator()() {};
};

int main() {
    run thread_r;
    thread t(thread_r);
    t.join();
}
```

example output:

```
in run()
copied()
moved()
in ~run()
in ~run()
in ~run()
```

Here's an updated version to help explain what's happening in the constructors and destructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class run {
public:
    run()
    : lifetime("constructed")
    { 
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
    }

    run(const run& other)
    : lifetime("copied from " + other.lifetime)
    { 
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
    }
    run(run&& other) 
    : lifetime("move-constructed from " + other.lifetime)
    { 
        other.lifetime = "[zombie] - " + other.lifetime;
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
    }
    run& operator=(const run& other) 
    { 
        lifetime = "copy assigned from " + other.lifetime + ", was once " + lifetime; 
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
        return *this; 
    }

    run& operator=(run &&other) 
    { 
        lifetime = "move-assigned from " + other.lifetime + ", was once " + lifetime; 
        other.lifetime = "[zombie] - " + other.lifetime;
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
        return *this; 
    }

    ~run() 
    {
        lifetime = "lifetime ending: " + lifetime;
        cout << lifetime << endl; 
    }

    void operator()() {};

    std::string lifetime;    
};

int main() {
    run thread_r;
    thread t(thread_r);
    t.join();
}
```

sample output:

```
constructed
copied from constructed
move-constructed from copied from constructed
lifetime ending: [zombie] - copied from constructed
lifetime ending: move-constructed from copied from constructed
lifetime ending: constructed
```

For anyone not sure about the exact behaviour of copy constructors and move-constructors, it would be a good idea to play with this code in a debugger until it becomes clear.

Comment: Just to make sure everyone understands, there's nothing in the language that *requires* you follow the rule of 5/3/0, but you do need to do so or risk all sorts of bugs and confusion.

Comment: I'm confused: in your example why is there the original and a copy (two objects) and three destructions?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah first constructor is when you create it in main, copy happens when you pass it to thread, the move happens when the copy is moved inside the call to thread. Even though the copy is moved-from, it is still destructed. It's still an object, and still needs cleaning up. A moved-from object is in a "valid but unspecified" state, from the point of view of the user of the object.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah added a more complete lifetime analysis to demonstrate exactly what's going on.

Comment: @RichardHodges Maybe for completeness - it is a good idea to add also output in case when the thread_r is passed using std::move. Thanks for your sample